# ¿Como usar serialize en un formulario con input de tipo File?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario en html para registrar un producto para ello uso ajax, cuando hago un serialize al formulario logro obtener todos los campos del mismo a excepción del campo de tipo file se que con FormData(), puedo obtener este campo pero me gustaría saber hay un manera con serialize para obtenerlo.

```
function ajaxRequest(url, method, data, datatype, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: datatype,
    type: method,
    // cache: false,
    // contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
      eval(successCallback + '(' + JSON.stringify(response) + ')');
    },
    error: function(error){
      eval(successCallback + '(' + JSON.stringify(error) + ')');
    }
  });
}

$('#crear-producto').click(function(){
    let data = $('#nuevo-producto').serialize();
    // let file = new FormData();
    // data = {
    //   'datos': $('#nuevo-producto').serialize(),
    //   'file': file.append('imagen', $('#imagen-producto')[0])
    // };
    ajaxRequest(constants.URL.PRODUCTOS.CREAR, 'POST', data, 'json', 'successRequest', 'errorRequest');
  });

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="nuevo-producto">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="producto" class="control-label">Producto:</label>
              <input type="text" name="producto" id="producto" class="form-control border-green" value="{% if p is defined %}{{ p.nombre }} {% endif %}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="marca" class="control-label">Marca:</label>
              <select class="form-control get-dependency border-green" name="marca" id="marca" data-element="referencia" >
                <option selected disabled>--Seleccionar--</option>
                {% for marca in marcas %}
                    <option value="{{ marca.id }}">{{ marca.nombre }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="referencia" class="control-label">Referencia:</label>
              <select class="form-control border-green" name="referencia" id="referencia">
                <option selected disabled>--Seleccionar--</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="precio" class="control-label">Valor Unidad</label>
              <input type="number" name="precio" id="precio" class="form-control border-green" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="unidades" class="control-label">Unidades:</label>
              <input type="number" name="unidades" id="unidades" class="form-control border-green" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="genero" class="control-label">Genero:</label>
              <select class="form-control border-blue" name="genero" id="genero" >
                <option selected disabled>--Seleccionar--</option>
                {% for genero in generos %}
                    <option value="{{ genero.id }}">{{ genero.nombre }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="estado" class="control-label">Estado:</label>
              <select class="form-control border-blue" name="estado" id="estado" >
                <option selected disabled>--Seleccionar--</option>
                {% for estado in estados %}
                    <option value="{{ estado.id }}">{{ estado.nombre }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="lanzamiento" class="control-label">Lanzamiento:</label>
              <input type="date" name="lanzamiento" id="lanzamiento" class="form-control border-blue" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="" class="control-label" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">Calificación:</label><br>
              <span class="clasificacion">
                <input class="estrella" id="radio1" name="estrellas" value="5" type="radio">
                <label for="radio1" class="label-estrella">&#9733;</label>
                <input class="estrella" id="radio2" name="estrellas" value="4" type="radio">
                <label for="radio2" class="label-estrella">★</label>
                <input class="estrella" id="radio3" name="estrellas" value="3" type="radio">
                <label for="radio3" class="label-estrella">★</label>
                <input class="estrella" id="radio4" name="estrellas" value="2" type="radio">
                <label for="radio4" class="label-estrella">★</label>
                <input class="estrella" id="radio5" name="estrellas" value="1" type="radio">
                <label for="radio5" class="label-estrella">★</label>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label for="imagen-producto" class="control-label">Imagen del producto</label>
              <input type="file" name="imagen-producto" id="imagen-producto" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="button" value="Crear Producto" class="btn btn-success pull-right enviar" id="crear-producto"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Yo quería hacer lo mismo pero no logre, termine usando un plugin de JQuery,  [Bootstrap File Input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo)

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tienes tu función `ajaxRequest`? Por lo general jQuery procesa los datos antes de enviarlos, para evitar que esto suceda tienes que pasarle la opción `processData: false`

Comment: Si mi función ajaxRequest ya tiene esta opción...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer no hay forma de hacerlo con `serialize()`, para tu caso se puede hacer con `FormData` de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#crear-producto').click(function(){
    let data = new FormData($('#nuevo-producto')[0]);
    ajaxRequest(constants.URL.PRODUCTOS.CREAR, 'POST', data, 'json', 'successRequest', 'errorRequest');
});
```

La información del form la podrás obtener de `$_POST` y la de los archivos de `$_FILES`.
Es importante también asignarle a los parámetros el valor de `contentType: false` porque si no jQuery lo enviará como `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` que es su valor por defecto.

Tu función `ajaxRequest` quedaría así:

```
function ajaxRequest(url, method, data, datatype, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: datatype,
    type: method,
    // Ambos importantes para que jQuery no transforme la información
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
      eval(successCallback + '(' + JSON.stringify(response) + ')');
    },
    error: function(error){
      eval(successCallback + '(' + JSON.stringify(error) + ')');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Vale entiendo pero según veo los otros datos del formulario como los enviaría?

Comment: @user22090 al hacer `new FormData($('#nuevo-producto')[0])` todos los valores de los inputs están dentro de `data`

Comment: Gracias @user22090 fuiste de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

> No se puede cargar un archivo y utilizar `serialize()` con **AJAX** porque no puede acceder al contenido de un archivo almacenado en la computadora cliente y enviarlo en la solicitud utilizando javascript.

Te recomiendo utilizar **FormData objects** te dejo un ejemplo que yo utilizo mucho.

```
function upload_files(url, inputFile, input_text, another_variable, form){
    //Obtenemos el campo de file del formulario 
    var archivos = $(inputFile)[0];
    var archivo = archivos.files; 
    var archivos = new FormData();

    //Para múltiples archivos 
    for(i=0; i<archivo.length; i++){
        archivos.append('archivo'+i,archivo[i]); //Añadimos cada archivo a el arreglo con un indice direfente
    }
    /**
     * Si queremos añadir alguna variable extra, por ejemplo algun campo tipo text
     */
    archivos.append('input_text', input_text);
    //Otra variable
    archivos.append('another_variable', another_variable);

    $.ajax({
        //Url_destino
        url:url,
        //Progress Bar
        xhr: function(){
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            //Upload progress
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total)*100;
                    //Do something with upload progress
                    form.find('.progress').removeClass('hidden');
                    form.find('.bar').css('width',percentComplete+'%');

                    if(percentComplete == 100){
                        setTimeout(function(){ 
                            //Progress Bar effect
                            form.find('.progress').addClass('hidden');
                            form.find('.bar').css('width','0%'); 
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            }, false);
            //Download progress
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    //Do something with download progress
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        type:'POST',
        contentType:false, //Debe estar en false para que pase el objeto sin procesar
        data:archivos, //Le pasamos el objeto que creamos con los archivos
        processData:false, //Debe estar en false para que JQuery no procese los datos a enviar
        cache:false,
        success: function(data){
            //Hacer algo con la data
       },
       error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            console.log(msg);
        },
    });
}
```

Se utiliza de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#upload_files').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = 'url/to/action.php';
            var input_text =  $('input[type=text]').val();
            var action_event =  $(this).find('.action_event').val();
            upload_files(url, '#files', input_text, action_event, $('#upload_files'));
            //Para borrar el formulario después de envíarlo y que todo salga ok
            $(this)[0].reset();
        });
```

El Html seria algo como:

```
<form  id="upload_files">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple="multiple" required>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="height: 10px; box-shadow: none; margin: 0; background-color:white;" class="hidden">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                            </div>
<input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

Comment: Entiendola lógica y me gustaría ahorrar un poco de líneas. Si yo envío todo el formulario de esta manera dentro dej ajax en la sección data: $('#formTerminarPerfil').serialize(), ¿Puedo obtener el mismo resultado?

Answer (score 1):

en lugar de serialize se usa FomData de la siguiente forma:

let data = new FormData($('#formImagen')[0]);

donde #formImagen es el id del formulario que recibe el archivo

adjunto código que me ayudo a resolver el problema

```
  $(function() {
    var url = $("#formImagen").attr("action"); //obtener url del action del form

    $("#formImagen").submit(function(e) { //si se presiono el botón del formulario
      e.preventDefault();

      var input = document.getElementById("archivo_imagen").value; //obtener valor de input

      if (input != "") {
        if ( input.endsWith(".jpg") || input.endsWith(".png")) {

          let data = new FormData($('#formImagen')[0]); //obtener dato de formulario tipo archivo
          $.ajax({
              url: url,
              method: "POST",
              data: data,
              contentType: false, //para archivos
              processData: false //para archivos
            })
            .done(function(r, textStatus, xhr) { //si se logro ejecutar
              if (xhr.status == 200) {
                location.reload(true); //recargar la pagina
              } else {
                swal("error al enviar datos", "", "error");
              }
            }).fail(function(error) {
              swal('', error.response, 'error');
            });

        } else {
          swal("ERROR, Formato invalido", "el archivo debe tener extensión .jpg/.png", "error");
        }
      } else {
        swal("ERROR", "campos vacios", "error");
      }
    })
  });
```